# How can get all commits from branch and put in single commit

Tags: git, version-control

I have this

```
A-----1'--2'--3'--4'  (master)
 \
  \
   D-----1--2--3--4--5--6--7--8--9 (dev)
```

what i want get all chnages from `D - 9` since diverge from master and then put all in one commit and make new branch `dev2` which will have all chnages from dev branch

There are 30 commits  in there

Comment: It would help if you could also show a diagram for how the `dev2` branch will look, relative to the two branches you already showed us above.

Comment: dev2 i have to create from fresh master

Comment: Then branch off master, rebase on `dev`, and squash the `dev` commits down to one, or however many you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already created `dev2` from `master` branch:

```
A-----1'--2'--3'--4'  (master, dev2)
 \
  \
   D-----1--2--3--4--5--6--7--8--9 (dev)
```

Then you can get all commits from `dev` branch into one commit to `dev2` by:

```
git checkout dev2
git merge dev --squash
```

Now the commit history will be (commit `M` is the merge commit which contains all the changes from `dev` branch):

```
              (master)
                  |
A-----1'--2'--3'--4'---M (dev2)
 \
  \                          
   D-----1--2--3--4--5--6--7--8--9 (dev)
```

Answer (score 0):

1.Create branch dev2 from master
2.take latest of dev
3.checkout dev2
4.merge dev into dev2